# I'm creating cmd command prompt from scratch

Tags: c++

I'm trying to build my own CMD from scratch with my own twist into it and I'm stuck on this and i wondering if anybody can point me in right direction.

it looks like this : C:>
I'm trying to make it where if you type echo "Hello World" it should only print "Hello World" If i use if(s == s){  then it will print Hello World without echo but i can aslo use any other word i want it will still print it i just only want it to be echo to make it print it. If you can point me in right direction that would be awesome thanks.

```
     if (s == "echo"){

         cout << s.substr(4) << '\n';
     } else {
     }
      }
```

Comment: you need to change the condition to: if(s.substr(0,4) == "echo")

Comment: thanks man you awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s == "echo"` compares the whole string stored in `s` to "echo". You need to inly compare the first 4 letters of the string to "echo". Do:

```
if (s.substr(0, 4) == "echo")
```

Comment: Also consider upvoting the answer if you liked it :)

Comment: @ScottyStultz If my answer worked, could you select the checkmark next to my answer? It should turn green when you do so. Thanks!